# Finding Angle BDF inside a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

[image]

Find Angle BDF

What i tried
Since Angle AOE is twice Angle ACE, we have Angle ACE= $(360-214)/2=73$ degrees.

Angle OET and Angle TAO is $90$ degrees since its a tangent line to the circle.

Angle ATE can then be found by taking $360-90-90-146=24$ degrees

Im unsure how to continue from here. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Well, do you think T is helpful here at all?

Comment: I was thinking, from T i could find Angle TOE and Angle AOT and from here maybe it could lead me to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

- From reflex $\angle AOE$,  compute $\angle AFE$.
- Justify why $\angle BDF = \angle BEF$.
- Use the fact that $AF$ and $BE$ are parallel to each other and since you have computed $\angle AFE$ to compute $\angle BEF $